# How do you check the first letter of the first tuple in a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So i have something like this

```
userPassList=[('*username','password'),('username2','password2'),('username3','password3')]
```

and i want to search through the list for the username with * as the first character.

I was thinking something like:

```
i=0
while i < len(self.userPassList):
    if (self.userPassList[i][:1]=='*'):
        self.conn.sendall(self.userPassList[i][1:])
    i= i+1
```

but this isnt quite right. Any ideas or suggestions?

Edit: I don't have the password just the username.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to not need an index variable. So use `for ... in ...` rather than `while ... i+=1`.

```
for tpl in list_of_tpls:
```

With that done, you'll have a tuple as your itervalue, so you can use `i[0]` just as you have been doing. You should probably go ahead and store that in a local variable, since you refer to it more than once. It'll be faster, *and* clearer.

```
    username = tpl[0]
```

Strings are treated as arrays/lists/tuples: they can be indexed. The way to check the value of the first character is either to use `.startswith()` or `[0]`.

```
    if username.startswith('*'):
    # ... or ...
    if username[0] == '*':
```

You've got the rest, I think.

Comment: i dont have the tpl tho. i only have the first element of the tuple in this case the username

Comment: Of course you have the tuple. Each element of the list-of-tuples is a tuple.

Comment: Again the tpl exists, but i dont know what the tuple is. Only the first element of the tuple. I do not know what the second element is.

Comment: Which is fine. You just want to get `tpl[0]` - that's the username.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to produce what you think it will.

Try running sections of code all by itself.
Make sure the line (starting with `userPassList=`...) is syntactically correct before writing a program that deals with it.

Here is why:

```
 username = 'me'
 username2 = 'me2'
 username3= 'me3'
 password = password2 = password3 = ''
 userPassList=[(*username,password),(username2,password2),(username3,password3)]
 print(userPassList)
 [('m', 'e', ''), ('me2', ''), ('me3', '')]
```

'*' in this case will give you an iterable and iterate through so that the tuple is longer than expected.

Perhaps you mean:

```
 username = '*me'
 username2 = 'me2'
 username3= 'me3'
 password = password2 = password3 = ''
 userPassList=[(username,password),(username2,password2),(username3,password3)]
 print(userPassList)
 [('*me', ''), ('me2', ''), ('me3', '')]
```

Then the rest of your programming efforts would make more sense.

Comment: I have manipulated the list and it works, but what i'm trying to do now requires me not to know the second tuple; the password. So this has made it a little harder.

Comment: Thanks I see what your saying im going to edit my post

Answer (score 1):

This is how it looks in idiomatic Python:

```
# Loop through the list until first hit.
for username, password in userPassList:  # Unpack the tuple as we fetch it.
  if username.startswith('*'):  # No mucking with indexes.
    self.conn...  # whatever
    break # We only need the first username
```

Comment: That's great but i dont know what the password is. Is there anyway i can say for username, _ in userPassList?

Comment: Yes, you can use `_` for variables you do not care about when destructuring a tuple, etc. Please remember that it's a regular identifier, not special syntax. (Also, in Python REPL, it is assigned the value of last evluated expression.) I took the 'password' from the structure of the data in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Well the `i = i + 1` needs to be outside of the if block, and instead of `[:1]` you could just use `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it looks in idiomatic functional python:

```
try:
   self.conn.sendall(next((name[1:len(name)] for name, _ in userPassList if name.startswith('*')))
except StopIteration:
   pass
```